# Node.js express NPM start error, Exit Status 8

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-ec2

i just installed node.js on Amazon EC2, and everything was working fine, then i stopped the server, and tried to start it again, and now i am getting this error:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1042:14)
    at listen (net.js:1064:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1138:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/CloudChat/server.js:34:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
npm ERR! application-name@0.0.1 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the application-name@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the application-name package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node server.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls application-name
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Linux 3.4.73-64.112.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! cwd /home/CloudChat
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.4
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/CloudChat/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

npm-debug.log contains this:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@1.4.4
3 info using node@v0.10.26
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info prestart application-name@0.0.1
6 info start application-name@0.0.1
7 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 info application-name@0.0.1 Failed to exec start script
9 error application-name@0.0.1 start: `node server.js`
9 error Exit status 8
10 error Failed at the application-name@0.0.1 start script.
10 error This is most likely a problem with the application-name package,
10 error not with npm itself.
10 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
10 error     node server.js
10 error You can get their info via:
10 error     npm owner ls application-name
10 error There is likely additional logging output above.
11 error System Linux 3.4.73-64.112.amzn1.x86_64
12 error command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
13 error cwd /home/CloudChat
14 error node -v v0.10.26
15 error npm -v 1.4.4
16 error code ELIFECYCLE
17 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

All i did was rename app.js to server.js, i also changed it in package.json, but it worked right after, until i stopped the server?

```
**EDIT** 

Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             Stat                        e
tcp        0      0 *:webcache                  *:*                         LIST                        EN
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                       *:*                         LIST                        EN
tcp        0      0 *:hbci                      *:*                         LIST                        EN
tcp        0      0 localhost:smtp              *:*                         LIST                        EN
tcp        0    320 ip-172-31-34-214.us-wes:ssh 78-143-78-51-customer.:6639 ESTA                        BLISHED
tcp        0      0 ip-172-31-34-214.us-wes:ssh 78-143-78-51-customer.:8846 ESTA                        BLISHED
tcp        0      0 ip-172-31-34-214.us-wes:ssh 78-143-78-51-customer.:8212 ESTA                        BLISHED
tcp      429      0 ip-172-31-34-214.u:webcache 78-143-78-51-customer.:8048 CLOS                        E_WAIT
tcp        0      0 ip-172-31-34-214.us-wes:ssh 78-143-78-51-custom:fs-mgmt ESTA                        BLISHED
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                       *:*                         LIST                        EN
udp        0      0 *:bootpc                    *:*                                                     
udp        0      0 ip-172-31-34-214.us-west:ntp *:*                                                    
udp        0      0 localhost:ntp               *:*                                                     
udp        0      0 *:ntp                       *:*                                                     
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     6526   /var/run/dbus/system_bu                        s_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     5537   @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  12     [ ]         DGRAM                    6469   /dev/log
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     5611   @/org/kernel/udev/udevd
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     52862
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     52861
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    52858
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    44741
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    44722
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     41225
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     41224
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    41221
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     40807
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     40806
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    40803
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    40121
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     38240
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     38239
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    38236
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    11231
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    7465
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    7446
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    7428
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    7347
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     6535   /var/run/dbus/system_bu                        s_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     6534
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     6530
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     6529
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    5627
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    5626
[root@ip-172-31-34-214 CloudChat]#
```

Comment: Still getting the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how to shut down express if you happen to have the same situation as me:

```
ps aux | grep node
Find the process ID (second from the left):
kill -9 PRCOCESS_ID
```

Comment: Gives the process ID # lsof -P | grep ':3000' | awk '{print $2}'

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that the port is already in use or you dont have permission to bind that port.

Try changing the listening port of the HTTP server or running the server as root using `sudo node app.js`

Comment: i did, but the port being in use could be the issue, thanks for the info

Comment: have you checked what is using that port? `netstat -a`

Comment: I set the app to listen on port 8080 which redirects to port 80, the port does not seem to be in use, i added the output to the question

Answer (score 0):

With Express 4 the start script is located in ./bin/www

If you have this error (like me) just edit it and replace

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

by

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || YOUR_PORT_NUMBER);
```